# CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface: Get pixels from IOSurfaceRef

Tags: macos, buffer, pixel, cvpixelbuffer, iosurface

I'm trying to create a `CVPixelBufferRef` from an `IOSurfaceRef` in order to be able to **read its pixels values**.

The IOSurfaceRef is read from the Syphon ([website](https://syphon.github.io/) and [repo](https://github.com/syphon)) framework's `SyphonOpenGLClient`. My code is inspired from the Simple Client example that can be found [here](https://github.com/Syphon/Simple/blob/master/Simple%20Client/SimpleClientAppDelegate.m) and is based on the Apple's documentation about [CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456968-cvpixelbuffercreatewithiosurface?language=objc).

Here it is:

```
m_client = [[SyphonOpenGLClient alloc] initWithServerDescription:[serverDescription copy]
                                                              context:CGLGetCurrentContext()
                                                              options:nil 
                                                      newFrameHandler:^(SyphonOpenGLClient *client) {

      // Get the new frame produced by the client.
      SyphonImageBase *frame = (SyphonImageBase *)[client newFrameImage];

      // It works: IOSurfaceRef exists.
      m_width = IOSurfaceGetWidth((IOSurfaceRef)[frame surface]);
      m_height = IOSurfaceGetHeight((IOSurfaceRef)[frame surface]);

      CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
      CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface(kCFAllocatorDefault, (IOSurfaceRef)[frame surface], NULL, &buffer);

      // Logs 0x0
      NSLog(@"Buffer: %p", buffer);

    }];
```

I'm really not a specialist of `CoreVideo`, I'm tinkering a lot.

I would like to understand **how to get pixels from an IOSurfaceRef**.

Thank you.